# Is there a way to generate one time use license?

Tags: truelicense

Testing generating multiple license on a same product. I'm able to install - uninstall - install the same license.

I want to know if there is a way to avoid this. I mean, after installing, the license file convert into trash.

I didn't found any information on TrueLicense documentation about it.